# Confidence size and coverage probability in a confidence set?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

Let $\theta \in \Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R^d}$ be the parameter of interest and let $\theta_0$ be the true population parameter value.  Let $n$ be the sample size.

Let $CS_n$ be the confidence set for $\theta_0$ of level $(1-\alpha)$  obtaining by inverting a test, i.e.
$$
CS_n=\{\theta \in \Theta | T_n(\theta)\leq c_{1-\alpha}(\theta) \}
$$
where $T_n(\theta)$ is an appropriate test statistic and $c_{1-\alpha}(\theta)$ is the associated critical value.

Some definitions:

(1) Exact coverage probability of $CS_n$: $\mathbb{P}(\theta_0 \in CS_n)$. It should be $\geq (1-\alpha)$

(2) Asymptotic coverage probability of $CS_n$: $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(\theta_0 \in CS_n)$. It should be $\geq (1-\alpha)$

(3) Exact confidence size of $CS_n$: $inf_{\theta \in \Theta} \mathbb{P}(T_n(\theta)\leq c_{1-\alpha}(\theta))$

(4) Asymptotic confidence size of $CS_n$: $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}(inf_{\theta \in \Theta} \mathbb{P}(T_n(\theta)\leq c_{1-\alpha}(\theta)))$

Questions:

(a) Why in (2) we need $\liminf$ instead of $\lim $?

(b) Relation between (1) and (3)?

(c) Relation between (2) and (4)?

(d) Why in (3) and (4) we need to take $\inf_{\theta \in \Theta}$?